# Proof of gradient of L2-norm squared?

Tags: derivatives, normed-spaces

Would this proof for the gradient of $\left\| Ax-b\right\| _{2}^{2} = 2A^{T}(Ax-b)$ be rigorous enough?

Proof:

$\nabla \left\| Ax-b\right\| _{2}^{2}$

$=\dfrac{d}{dx} (Ax-b)^{T}(Ax-b) $

$= (Ax-b)^{T}A^{T} + (Ax-b)A $

$= 2A^{T}(Ax-b)$